# Как быстро найти файл, который отправляет на сервер форму?

Tags: post

Здравствуйте ещё раз.
Нет ли быстрого метода для поиска файлов .js которые делают POST?
Их тут тысячи, как найти нужный?
Может расширения Chrome?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можете воспользоваться средствами отладки Google Chrome. Откройте инструменты отладки нажатием `f12`, после чего выберите вкладку `network`, отфильтруйте запросы, оставив только `xhr` запросы. И в столбце `Initiator` увидите тот файл, который делает запрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы понять `POST` или `GET` запрос, нажмите на него и вы получите описание на вкладке `Header`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а если страница сразу же перезагружается и я не успеваю заметить какой файл отработал? Есть способ на этот случай?

Comment: У меня получилось, спасибо. Записал на видео :)

Comment: @АлександрМишура Можете поставить галочку `Preserve log`, и тогда у вас будут сохраняться запросы после перезагрузки.